# Problems with Snippet Syntax Highligher Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I feel as though this will end up being a silly question with a silly answer but I genuinely can't see what is wrong.

I am trying to use the JQuery snippet plugin: http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/

I include the scripts in my footer:

```
<script src="js/jquery.snippet.js"></script>
<script src="js/specific-styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // $("pre.code").snippet("php",{style:"neon"}); // tried this first of all
    $(".code").snippet("php",{style:"neon",clipboard:"js/ZeroClipboard.swf"});
});
```

and the css in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.snippet.css" type="text/css" />
```

and my markup is as follows:

```
<pre class="code">&lt;?php echo "&copy; 2008 - " . date("Y") ?&gt;</pre>
```

But on my web page it simply looks like a normal `<pre>` kind of styling with no highlighting.

As far as I can tell I have done the right things to use the plugin so I was just wondering if anyone on here could help.

No reports on Firebug about it.

Comment: fix your <script src="js/specific-styles.js"</script>

Comment: Apart from @ric_bfa annotation, any JS problem? Did you linked jquery first, didnt' you?

Comment: oops, sorry. I have fixed that and jquery is linked first. Only JS problem is with another plugin. I tried removing it but code still looks the same as before

Comment: If firebug didn't throw any $ is undefined errors before you included jQuery first, I'd be inclined to say there's something else going on.
The first time that snippet plugin calls the $jQuery object, it should throw an error because jQuery was not loaded. May be an issue with firebug, have you tried it on Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Can you put this on jsFiddle or link to a demo?

Comment: Hi, I will try and create a fiddle later when I get home.

Comment: Seems to work as you're describing. See this [http://jsfiddle.net/fYWSz/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/fYWSz/1/). Do you have other CSS being applied, or other JavaScript that may be conflicting?

Comment: @jo8691 - thanks for making the snippet, I will need to take a look and see if there are any conflicts. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put jQuery in "no-conflict" mode first, right after it`s inclusion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```